# why custom checkbox textview overwrite on checkbox button?

Tags: android, checkbox, textview, padding

[image] Here i am using custom checkbox but texview of checkbox overwrite button.
what i should do? i try to some padding but its work some devices fine but in some text display more left-paading, while in some overwrite what i should do?

here is xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"



xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="sportsquiz.QuizActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_noID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_questionID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DCE3E6" >
```

```
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_ans1ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#DCE3E6" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_ans2ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#DCE3E6" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_ans3ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#DCE3E6" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_ans4ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_nextID"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/circled_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

please anyone help me what i am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  android:id="@+id/chk_ans1ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="CheckBox" 
            android:background="#00000000"/>
```

for java code.

```
ans_1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
```

(R.drawable.custom_checkbox_crossed, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/chk_ans3ID"
   android:layout_width="64dp"
   android:layout_height="64dp"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
   android:button="@null"
   android:drawablePadding="5dp"
   android:text="CheckBox" 
   android:background="#00000000"/>
```